# hdfs copy multiple files to same target directory

Tags: hadoop, copy, hdfs, subdirectory, cp

I learned that if you want to copy multiple files from one hadoop folder to another hadoop folder you can better create one big 'hdfs dfs -cp' statement with lots of     components, instead of creating several hdfs dfs -cp statements.
With 'better' I mean that it will improve the overal time it takes to copy files: one command is quicker than several separate -cp commands run after each other.

When I do this and my target directory is the same for all files that I want to copy I get a warning.

I'm executing the following command:

```
hdfs dfs -cp -f /path1/file1 /pathx/target /path2/file2 /pathx/target /path3/file3 /pathx/target
```

After executing it I get the following warning returned:

```
cp: `/pathx/target' to `/pathx/target/target': is a subdirectory of itself
```

Although I get this weird warning the copy itself succeeds like it should.
Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to use the following syntax:

```
hadoop fs -cp /path1/file1 /path2/file2 path3/file3 /pathx/target
```

Comment: ughh that was is. Thanks! I should have check the documentation first...
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#cp

so it's 
`hdfs dfs -cp source1 source2 source3 target`

Answer (score 1):

Or You could do it like this:

```
hadoop fs -cp /path1/{file1, file2, file3} /pathx/target
```

If you want to copy all the files then:

```
hadoop fs -cp /path1/* /pathx/target
```

Answer (score 0):

-cp did not worked for me...
I used the following and it worked

```
hdfs dfs -put /path1/file1 /path2/file2 path3/file3 /pathx/target
```